# ¿Como validar un Bucle hasta que se cumpla la condición?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Quisiera generar un 'codigo' aleatorio y validar si existe o no (en la tabla de una base de datos), en caso de que exista debera de generarse nuevamente el codigo la cantidad de veces que sea necesaria hasta que se valide que no existe y asi poder insertar un registro y retonar ese codigo.

**CODIGO**

```
 while($queryProducts )
            {
              for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++):
                $code = mt_rand(0, 9);
              endfor;

              if(empty($this->validateRegister($code, $datos = false))):                
                $queryProducts = $this->db->insert('producs',[
                  'id_rates' => $datos['rates'],
                  'id_estableshiment' => $this->session->userdata('id_user_establishment'),
                  'barcode' => $code,
                  'name' => $datos['name'],
                  'description' => $datos['description'],             
                  'entry_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                ]);
              endif;
            }

if($queryTickets):
            $msj = $code;
          endif;

return $msj;
```

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es la necesidad de reinventar la rueda en lugar de utilizar un autoincremental o un uuid. ¿Podrías desarrollar un poco más los requerimientos?

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría algo así (más o menos):

```
$seguir = true;
while($seguir){

          for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++):
              $code = mt_rand(0, 9);
          endfor;

     //haces un count para saber si existe ese código en DB. No recuerdo como se hará en codeigniter pero será algo parecido a esto, imagino:
          $count = $this->db->where('barcode',$code);
                   $this->db->from("producs");
                   $this->db->count_all_results();

          if(!$count){
                   $queryProducts = $this->db->insert('producs',[
                                    'id_rates' => $datos['rates'],
                                    'id_estableshiment' => $this->session->userdata('id_user_establishment'),
                                    'barcode' => $code,
                                    'name' => $datos['name'],
                                    'description' => $datos['description'],             
                                    'entry_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                   ]);
                   $seguir = false;
          }
}
```

Es decir, inicializas la variable $seguir a true para que entre por primera vez en el bucle, y luego sólo redeclararás esta variable a false si entras en el if() (es decir, si ese count te devuelve un cero) donde se haces la inserción, de forma que no vuelva a iterar otra vez.

Nota: no copies y pegues el código tal cual. Me he saltado tu validación y el if que haces al final, vale? Pero la idea que buscas creo que es esa.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más práctica de que lleves a cabo eso es de la siguiente manera:

Vas a generar el código aleatorio: `$code = mt_rand();`

Y para verificar si ese código ya existe basta con que hagas un select mandando el código y si te retorna true es que ese código ya esta registrado, de lo contrario te va a retornar un false en donde puede proceder a registrar ese código.

Controlador:

```
public function principal()
{
    $code = mt_rand();
    if(!$this->Tu_model->verificaCodigo($code)){
      // Si retorna false, entonces el codigo no existe
      // Y aqui procedes a registrarlo
      $this->Tu_model->registraCodigo($code);
    }
    // Si retorna true, entonces el codigo existe por lo tanto
    // puedes volver a llamar a la funcion para que genere otro
    $this->principal();
}
```

Modelo:

```
public function verificaCodigo($code)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->where('codigo', $code);

    $Result = $this->db->get();

    if (!$Result->num_rows() == 1) {
        // Retorna falso si no encuentra registros
        return false;
    }
    // Retorna true si encuentra registros
    return true;
}
```

Y para insertar tu registro puedes crear el arreglo de datos desde el controlador y dicho arreglo pasarlo al modelo y puedes realizar la inserción mas fácilmente.

Controlador:

```
public function principal()
{
    $code = mt_rand();
    if(!$this->Tu_model->verificaCodigo($code)){
      // Si retorna false, entonces el codigo no existe
      // Y aqui procedes a registrarlo
      $data = array(
            'id_rates' => $datos['rates'],
            'id_estableshiment' => $this->session->userdata('id_user_establishment'),
            'barcode' => $code,
            'name' => $datos['name'],
            'description' => $datos['description'],
            'entry_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
      $this->Tu_model->registraCodigo($data);
    }
    // Si retorna true, entonces el codigo existe por lo tanto
    // puedes volver a llamar a la funcion para que genere otro
    $this->principal();
}
```

Solo creas tu función para insertar en el modelo y listo una vez que quede `$this->Tu_model->registraCodigo($data);` no necesitas retornar el código porque puedes acceder a el directamente desde el arreglo o con la variable `$code`.